# Can't find manager application in a tomcat9 from docker

Tags: docker, tomcat9

When I run a tomcat docker image:
`docker run -it --rm tomcat:9.0`

it starts properly so I can see some output from http://localhost:8080/
if I go to http://localhost:8080/manager/html it returns 404 and there is no manager application under /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.
I think I am missing something, how do I enable the manager application?

Answer (score 3):

> there is no manager application under /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

This is because by default the contents in `webapps` moved to `webapps.dist`:

```
root@0a08d2dcf78e:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist# ls
ROOT  docs  examples  host-manager  manager
```

[tomcat dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat) mentioned the reason as next:

> Note: as of [docker-library/tomcat#181](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/pull/181), the upstream-provided (example) webapps are not enabled by default, per [upstream's security recommendations](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-howto.html#Default_web_applications), but are still available under the webapps.dist folder within the image to make them easier to re-enable.

So, for you, you need do [next](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/pull/181#issuecomment-569817484) to make it work:

```
cp -avT $CATALINA_HOME/webapps.dist/manager $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager
```